# Selecting rows from sparse dataframe by index position

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, sparse-matrix

In a typical python dataframe, it's easy to select desired rows based on index:

```
df.ix[list_of_inds] or df.loc[list_of_inds]
```

However, using this method to take a substantial subset of a large, sparse dataframe (73,000 rows, 8,000 columns specifically) seems to be extremely intensive - my memory shoots up and my computer crashes.

I did notice that indexing using a range like this..

```
df.ix[1:N]
```

works fine, while using a list of indices like this...

```
df.ix[np.arange(1,N)]
```

is what makes the memory overload.

Is there another way to select rows from a sparse dataframe that's computationally easier? Or, can I convert this dataframe to an actual sparse matrix...

```
sparse_df = scipy.sparse.csc(df)
```

and select only the indices I want from that?

Comment: Have you tried the `to_sparse` method? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html

Comment: Trying it out - seems like it takes a while. Can the resulting dataframe from the to_sparse method be subsetted easily?  Edit: using to_sparse on my 73000x8000 dataframe crashed my computer

Comment: Did you try: `list_of_inds = pd.Index(list_of_inds); df.ix[list_of_inds]`?

Answer (score -1):

The issue you are facing could be related to view vs copy semantics.

```
df.ix[1:N]              # uses slicing => operates on a view 
df.ix[np.arange(1,N)]   # uses fancy indexing => "probably" creates a copy first
```

I created a DataFrame on my machine of shape 73000x8000 and my memory spiked to 4.4 GB so I wouldn't be surprised with crashes. That said, if you do need to create a new array with the index list, then you're out of luck. However, to modify the original DataFrame, you should be able to modify the DataFrame one row at a time, or few sliced rows at a time at the expense of speed, eg:

```
for i in arbitrary_list_of_indices:
    df.ix[i] = new_values
```

Btw, you could try working off numpy arrays directly which I felt has clearer descriptions of which operations result in copies vs views. You can always create a DataFrame from the array with hardly any memory overhead since it just creates a reference to the original array.

Also indexing in numpy seems much faster, even without slicing. Here's a simple testcase:

```
In [66]: df
Out[66]: 
    0   1   2   3
0   3  14   5   1
1   9  19  14   4
2   5   4   5   5
3  13  14   4   7
4   8  12   3  16
5  15   3  17  12
6  11   0  12   0

In [68]: df.ix[[1,3,5]]       # fancy index version
Out[68]: 
    0   1   2   3
1   9  19  14   4
3  13  14   4   7
5  15   3  17  12

In [69]: df.ix[1:5:2]   # sliced version of the same
Out[69]: 
    0   1   2   3
1   9  19  14   4
3  13  14   4   7
5  15   3  17  12

In [71]: %timeit df.ix[[1,3,5]] = -1   # use fancy index version
1000 loops, best of 3: 251 µs per loop

In [72]: %timeit df.ix[1:5:2] = -2     # faster sliced version
10000 loops, best of 3: 157 µs per loop

In [73]: arr = df.values
In [74]: arr
Out[74]: 
array([[ 3, 14,  5,  1],
       [-2, -2, -2, -2],
       [ 5,  4,  5,  5],
       [-2, -2, -2, -2],
       [ 8, 12,  3, 16],
       [-2, -2, -2, -2],
       [11,  0, 12,  0]])

In [75]: %timeit arr[[1,3,5]] = -1   # much faster than DataFrame
The slowest run took 23.49 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.56 µs per loop

In [77]: %timeit arr[1:5:2] = -3  # really fast but restricted to slicing
The slowest run took 19.46 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 821 ns per loop
```

Good luck!